# Is there a way to know when institution is buying to the level of days instead of quarters?

Tags: stock-markets

https://www.nasdaq.com/market-activity/stocks/amd/institutional-holdings

NASDAQ lists institution ownership only to the resolution of quarters. For example, the dates are 06/30/2021 which refers to the Q2 of 2021. Is three a resource that provide institution buying/selling days instead of quarters?

Answer (score 2):

No. That's the whole point of the system.

There is a balance to be struck between regulatory necessity and commercial confidentiality.

Daily data is commercially sensitive, quarterly data is sufficient for regulatory purposes.

Bonus answer:

I would also take a moment to warn you against trying to trade off institutional ownership data. It is inherently dirty data:

- It is (as you discovered) historical data covering a large period.
- It doesn't have the necessary level of detail to make it useful (i.e. own-book vs client).
- If the institution operates certain types of fund, you might be merely seeing the result of quarterly window-dressing.
- Many other aspects

Learn to make your own investment decisions, don't try to surf the waves others have created.

Comment: never mind that the system rewards you for surfing waves others are about to create